# OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device in AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

```
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 11187.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 2074.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 2066.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 2996.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ebtables ruleset management.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started AppArmor initialization.
         Starting Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd...
         Starting Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking)...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd.
[   34.900360] cloud-init[598]: Cloud-init v. 19.3-41-gc4735dd3-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 running 'init-local' at Tue, 29 Jun 2021 01:20:06 +0000. Up 34.78 seconds.
[   34.903453] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,217 - util.py[DEBUG]: Cloud-init v. 19.3-41-gc4735dd3-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 running 'init-local' at Tue, 29 Jun 2021 01:20:06 +0000. Up 34.78 seconds.
[   34.908199] cloud-init[598]: tee: /var/log/cloud-init-output.log: No space left on device
[   34.914945] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,298 - main.py[DEBUG]: No kernel command line url found.
[   34.917398] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,299 - main.py[DEBUG]: Closing stdin.
[   34.919574] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,308 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/log/cloud-init.log - ab: [644] 0 bytes
[   34.922767] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,309 - util.py[DEBUG]: Changing the ownership of /var/log/cloud-init.log to 102:4
[   34.928109] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,310 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
[   34.931105] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,310 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/data/no-net
[   34.934139] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,310 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: init-local/check-cache: attempting to read from cache [check]
[   34.938195] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,310 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl (quiet=False)
[   34.941052] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,310 - stages.py[DEBUG]: no cache found
[   34.951972] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,310 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-local/check-cache: SUCCESS: no cache found
[   34.954789] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,311 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance
[   34.957485] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,322 - stages.py[DEBUG]: Using distro class <class 'cloudinit.distros.ubuntu.Distro'>
[   34.960353] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,322 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Looking for data source in: ['Ec2', 'None'], via packages ['', 'cloudinit.sources'] that matches dependencies ['FILESYSTEM']
[   34.965181] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,355 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Searching for local data source in: ['DataSourceEc2Local']
[   34.968481] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,356 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: init-local/search-Ec2Local: searching for local data from DataSourceEc2Local
[   34.971708] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,356 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Seeing if we can get any data from <class 'cloudinit.sources.DataSourceEc2.DataSourceEc2Local'>
[   34.975077] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,358 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Update datasource metadata and network config due to events: New instance first boot
[   34.978839] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,358 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/hypervisor/uuid (quiet=False)
[   34.981652] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,359 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['systemd-detect-virt', '--quiet', '--container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   34.988297] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,387 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['running-in-container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   34.992860] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,391 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['lxc-is-container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   34.998238] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,397 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/1/environ (quiet=False)
[   35.000969] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,397 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 173 bytes from /proc/1/environ
[   35.003478] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,400 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/self/status (quiet=False)
[   35.006302] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,400 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 1300 bytes from /proc/self/status
[   35.008978] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,402 - util.py[DEBUG]: querying dmi data /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
[   35.011928] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,405 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid (quiet=False)
[   35.015111] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,405 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 37 bytes from /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
[   35.017959] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,408 - util.py[DEBUG]: dmi data /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid returned ec2142fb-189a-8bce-161e-77c116971ade
[   35.021426] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,408 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['systemd-detect-virt', '--quiet', '--container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   35.028753] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,427 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['running-in-container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   35.034152] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,433 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['lxc-is-container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   35.040104] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,438 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/1/environ (quiet=False)
[   35.042949] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,439 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 173 bytes from /proc/1/environ
[   35.045441] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,442 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/self/status (quiet=False)
[   35.048240] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,442 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 1300 bytes from /proc/self/status
[   35.051024] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,444 - util.py[DEBUG]: querying dmi data /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial
[   35.054759] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,444 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial (quiet=False)
[   35.058075] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,447 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 37 bytes from /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial
[   35.061160] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,450 - util.py[DEBUG]: dmi data /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial returned ec2142fb-189a-8bce-161e-77c116971ade
[   35.064796] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,450 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['systemd-detect-virt', '--quiet', '--container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   35.070157] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,469 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['running-in-container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   35.075489] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,474 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['lxc-is-container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   35.081189] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,480 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/1/environ (quiet=False)
[   35.083838] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,480 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 173 bytes from /proc/1/environ
[   35.086623] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,483 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/self/status (quiet=False)
[   35.089445] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,483 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 1300 bytes from /proc/self/status
[   35.092309] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,485 - util.py[DEBUG]: querying dmi data /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag
[   35.095225] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,488 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag (quiet=False)
[   35.098456] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,488 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 11 bytes from /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag
[   35.101570] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,491 - util.py[DEBUG]: dmi data /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag returned Amazon EC2
[   35.108234] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,491 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['systemd-detect-virt', '--quiet', '--container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   35.112615] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,507 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['running-in-container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   35.118170] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,517 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['lxc-is-container'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[   35.123792] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,522 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/1/environ (quiet=False)
[   35.126679] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,523 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 173 bytes from /proc/1/environ
[   35.129406] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,525 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/self/status (quiet=False)
[   35.132171] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,526 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 1300 bytes from /proc/self/status
[   35.134736] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,528 - util.py[DEBUG]: querying dmi data /sys/class/dmi/id/sys_vendor
[   35.137778] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,528 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/dmi/id/sys_vendor (quiet=False)
[   35.140885] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,531 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 11 bytes from /sys/class/dmi/id/sys_vendor
[   35.143746] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,531 - util.py[DEBUG]: dmi data /sys/class/dmi/id/sys_vendor returned Amazon EC2
[   35.146749] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,534 - DataSourceEc2.py[DEBUG]: strict_mode: warn, cloud_name=aws cloud_platform=ec2
[   35.149976] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,546 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /etc/os-release (quiet=False)
[   35.152874] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,549 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 386 bytes from /etc/os-release
[   35.155952] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,555 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens5/name_assign_type (quiet=False)
[   35.159274] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,555 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 2 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens5/name_assign_type
[   35.162300] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,558 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens5/carrier (quiet=False)
[   35.165346] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,561 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens5/dormant (quiet=False)
[   35.168849] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,564 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens5/operstate (quiet=False)
[   35.172017] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,564 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 5 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens5/operstate
[   35.174922] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,568 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens5/address (quiet=False)
[   35.177935] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,568 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens5/address
[   35.352176] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,751 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-local/search-Ec2Local: FAIL: no local data found from DataSourceEc2Local
[   35.355878] cloud-init[598]: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,751 - util.py[WARNING]: Getting data from <class 'cloudinit.sources.DataSourceEc2.DataSourceEc2Local'> failed
[   35.359069] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,751 - util.py[WARNING]: Getting data from <class 'cloudinit.sources.DataSourceEc2.DataSourceEc2Local'> failed
[   35.690396] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,751 - util.py[DEBUG]: Getting data from <class 'cloudinit.sources.DataSourceEc2.DataSourceEc2Local'> failed
```

I got above error messages in my AWS EC2 instance. Even when I've increased volume from 30Gi to 60Gi it didn't help. How can I resolve this issue?. I'm not sure do I need to increase volume it again or not.

Comment: You need to increase the disk from the operating system as well, first run 'df -T' to see what disk filesystem you are using, if it's 'ext4' see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/509468/how-to-extend-an-ext4-partition-and-filesystem) link. Also, I would recommend creating an AMI of the current EC2 instance, then create a new instance from the AMI. This will create the new instance with the volume extended.

Comment: Have you [extended the Linux file system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)?

Comment: @AlinAndrei I cannot ssh to that instance because we lost pem file, that's why I was supposed to install SSM manager on it. And, I've created AMI image and tried with 100g volume and got same result. So sad.

Comment: @jellycsc I cannot ssh to that instance.

Comment: What OS are you using in that EC2? The OS maybe a bit older, and the disk increase may require manual intervention.

Comment: You need to start with [recovering the ssh key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-lost-key-pair.html).

Comment: @AlinAndrei it's `Ubuntu (Inferred)`.

Comment: Can you check provisioning process  and file save path? It seems the process starts, then it fails as it's running out of space. Also, please ensure the path that the file(s) are saved, has enough space.

Comment: @AlinAndrei instance was out of space before that's why I've increased size to 60g. But now in logs, got following info `[   34.908199] cloud-init[598]: tee: /var/log/cloud-init-output.log: No space left on device
[   34.914945] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,298 - main.py[DEBUG]: No kernel command line url found.
[   34.917398] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,299 - main.py[DEBUG]: Closing stdin.
[   34.919574] cloud-init[598]: FALLBACK: 2021-06-29 01:20:06,308 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/log/cloud-init.log - ab: [644] 0 bytes`

Answer (score 1):

You should try just rebooting the machine through the AWS console.  There is a chance that cloud-init will expand the root partition to fill the available new space on reboot.

Comment: I don't think cloud-init will extend the volume automatically.